# Trying to get my chrome extension to click a element on page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that can download mp3s from hiphopdx. I have found that once you click the play button on the website it might be possible to extract the download link of the mp3. However I am stuck on getting my extension to click on the play button. 
Here is an example of the page on which I am using the extension on:
http://www.hiphopdx.com/index/singles/id.16603/title.fred-the-godson-f-the-kid-daytona-back-to-school-prod-kaimbr

my manifest json

```
"name": "My Test",
"version": "1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"]
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
},
"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
```

my popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function ShowOperationMessage(obj, evt) {
        var fireOnThis = obj;
        if (document.createEvent) {
            var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            evObj.initEvent(evt, true, false);
            fireOnThis.dispatchEvent(evObj);
        } else if (document.createEventObject) {
            fireOnThis.fireEvent('on' + evt);
        }
    }

ShowOperationMessage(document.getElementsByClassName("playBtns medium awesome red adjust launchplayer left"),"click");
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code to content scripts code, i was able to click the button

[image]

**References**

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Background Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)
- [Browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html)

Added content script section to eliminate background stuff

***manifest.json***

```
{
    "name": "Mouse Clicks",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This demonstrates how mouse clicks are tracked",
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.hiphopdx.com/index/singles/id.16603/title.fred-the-godson-f-the-kid-daytona-back-to-school-prod-kaimbr"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
      }
  ]

}
```

***myscript.js***

`document.getElementsByClassName("playBtns medium awesome red adjust launchplayer left")` returns an array so used `obj[0]` index

```
function ShowOperationMessage(obj, evt) {
    var fireOnThis = obj[0];
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evObj.initEvent(evt, true, false);
        fireOnThis.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    } else if (document.createEventObject) {
        fireOnThis.fireEvent('on' + evt);
    }
}

ShowOperationMessage(document.getElementsByClassName("playBtns medium awesome red adjust launchplayer left"), "click");
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: +user1874600 You dont need to click the button.  You can get its url like this `$(".playBtns").data().file`

Comment: @PAEz: In this code `<a href="/index/singles/" id="playBtn-16603" class="playBtns medium awesome red adjust launchplayer left" rel="nofollow">Play <span style="font-size:10px; margin-left:3px; width:auto !important; background:none !important; display:inline !important;">▶</span></a>` there is no data key, am i looking at wrong button?,

Comment: Its a jquery thing, I only recently learnt about that data() thing myself.  Try the code ;) worked for me.  Only prob would be if the js hasnt set that yet, but once the page has loaded should work fine.